# How can I reset PrimeFaces tabs

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have A PrimeFaces **wizard** each tab contains InputText fields or SelectOneMenu menus ... how could I reset all fields and menus in all tabs on submit button ??
I'm using primefaces 5.3
thank you

Comment: You don't reset tabs, you reset input fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeFaces has a component for clientside resets

```
 <p:commandButton value="Reset Tag" update="@form" process="@form" style="margin-right:20px;" >
     <p:resetInput target="***idFromYourTag***" />
 </p:commandButton>
```

If you need reset the backing bean values, you need to write a method.
See also [ResetInput](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml)

Comment: You are welcome